# Error using the library xml2js with React and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml

I have a React app that needs to parse some XML data. I plan to use a package to do this job. The packages `xml2js` and `@types/xml2js` are installed. During testing the following error appeared:

```
sax.js:222 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at sax.js:222:46
   ...
```

Here's the file containing the code. The syntax should be correct according to the docs. The other components shouldn't be causing this particular error since they are not wired to it yet.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import x2j from 'xml2js';

export default function EventWindow(props: { xml: string; }) {
  const {xml} = props;
  const [eventText, setEventText] = useState('');
  const [eventChoices, setEventChoices] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const ps = new x2j.Parser();
    ps.parseString(xml, (err, res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }, [xml])

  return (
    <div>
      <EventSimText text={eventText || "Error Detected."} />
      <EventSimChoices choicesArr={eventChoices} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem details are required before correcting.
For example, screenshots

Comment: Here's the issue replicated on stackblitz, if that helps. The error can be seen in the browser console. [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-wf9akd?file=src/Event.tsx)